# How to remove "?et_blog" pagination links parameter on Divi Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, divi, divi-theme

In my Project i'm using DIVI theme and i have use multiple custom post type like recipe, articles and so on.
and requirement is display that post in category archive page using pagination (without ajax)
but after doing code.

- site.com/page/2/ (not working)
- site.com/page/2/?et_blog (working)

if I remove "?et_blog" from url then page returning `404 error` don't know why this adding
please let me know if any solution is there ?

eg.url structure

- site.com/post_type/category/post-single
- site.com/post_type/category/post-single/page/2/

I need to remove ?et_blog from URL

I'd try to add custom pagination and create shortcode function and display shortcode on DIVI builder